# How to prevent the screen reader reads from the semantic element like banner or region

Tags: html, accessibility

In my application screen reader reads the semantic landmark as "Banner region region" each time, when come back to the previous page else opening the page at first time. i need a solution to avoid the landmark saying by the talk back.

I have tried to apply role="presentation" to header and section element but it makes the some problem when scrolling the page while talk back is ON.

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically try to use [native HTML elements that have the same implicit meaning as aria roles](https://dequeuniversity.com/assets/html/jquery-summit/html5/slides/landmarks.html#comparing_html5_to_aria). For example, the `<header>` element has the same semantic meaning as `role="banner"` and it won't be announced in the same way by screen readers. This method is generally less complicated and works better, in my opinion.